# Как достать данные из queryset django?

Tags: python, django, queryset

помогите пожалуйста разобраться. У меня есть такая модель:

```
class Rout_car(models.Model): #Класс маршрутных листов
YES = 'Да'
NO = 'Нет'
YENO_CHOICES = [
    (YES, 'ДА'),
    (NO, 'НЕТ'),

]
car_where_in = models.ForeignKey(Contragent,on_delete=models.CASCADE,verbose_name='Откуда',null=True)
car_where_out = models.ForeignKey(Contragent,on_delete=models.CASCADE,verbose_name='Куда', null=True, related_name='car_where_out_related')
rout_driver = models.ManyToManyField(RusRegions, verbose_name='Маршрут по регионам')
car_driver = models.ForeignKey(Driver, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, verbose_name='Водитель')
car_track = models.ForeignKey(Track, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, verbose_name='Тягач')
car_trailer = models.ForeignKey(Trailer, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, verbose_name='Прицеп')
promezhutok_punkt = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=YENO_CHOICES, verbose_name='Адреса промежуточных пунктов', null=True)
car_parking = models.CharField(max_length=100,choices=YENO_CHOICES ,verbose_name='Места стоянок', null=True)
car_gas_station = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=YENO_CHOICES,verbose_name='Места заправок топливом', null=True)
contr_agent = models.ForeignKey(Contragent,on_delete=models.CASCADE,verbose_name='Контрагент', null=True, related_name='contr_agent_related') # Позже добавлю справочник обработки
car_date = models.DateField(auto_now=False, null=True, verbose_name='Дата отправления')
class Meta:
    verbose_name = 'Маршрут'
    verbose_name_plural = 'Сформировать маршрут'

def __str__(self):
    return f'{self.car_driver.first_name + " " + self.car_driver.last_name}'#
```

В данной модели хранятся данные машин которые находятся в рейсе. Мне надо вывести эти данные в шаблон. Создал функцию в views.py:

```
def all_rout(request):
all = Rout_car.objects.all()
return render(request,'doc_track_app/save_data_doc.html',{'all':all})
```

при попытке вывести в шаблоне к примеру водителя:
{{ all.car_driver.first_name }} ничего не выводится, запускаю power shell в терминале, и он мне пишет:
'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'car_driver'
Объясните пожалуйста, как правильно доставать данные? В том же powershell если я делаю так:

```
 f = Rout_car.objects.all()
```

и печатаю значение f, я получаю:

```
<QuerySet [<Rout_car: Иванов Иван>, <Rout_car: Петров Петр>]>
```

Но вот дальше этих данных, ничего не могу получить =(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. [Queryset в Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated) - это iterable-объект, т.е., по сути, представляет собой спископодобный контейнер экземпляров модели. Следовательно, в шаблоне вам нужно [использовать тег `for`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/templates/builtins/#for) для перебора и вывода элементов queryset-а:

```
f = Rout_car.objects.all()
```

...

```
{% for rout_car in f %}
    {{ rout_car.car_driver.first_name }}
{% endfor %}
```

2. Предыдущий пример можно оптимизировать. Поле `car_driver` у вас - это `ForeignKey` к другой модели `Driver`, и по умолчанию запрос к queryset-у модели `Rout_car` "доставать" значения полей из связанных моделей не будет, следовательно, при каждом обращении к `.first_name` происходит новое обращение к БД. Можно явным образом указать, какие объекты вам нужны вместе с основным запросом, используя метод queryset-а [select_related()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/models/querysets/#select-related):

```
f = Rout_car.objects.select_related("car_driver").all()
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо вам Михаил!